# Codeigniter / Active Record Class generating blank IN()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some code in Codeigniter that looks like this:

```
$this->db->select('email_account_id');
$this->db->where('TRIM(LOWER(email_account_incoming_username))',trim(strtolower($email_address)));
$query = $this->db->get($this->users_db.'email_account');
```

Throws this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND TRIM(LOWER(email_account_incoming_username)) = 'email@server.co.uk'' at line 3
SELECT `email_account_incoming_username`, `email_account_id` FROM (`crmuat_users`.`email_account`) WHERE `email_account_id` IN () AND TRIM(LOWER(email_account_incoming_username)) = 'email@server.co.uk'
```

Now I don't for the life of me understand how the "IN()" got in there?

Anybody able to see?

Comment: I may just need to reinitialise the class?

Comment: SELECT `email_account_incoming_username` this isn't in the code...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have called the `$this->db->where_in()` method somewhere. It is impossible for CodeIgniter Active Record to generate the `IN()` clause unless you tell it to do so. Try to see if you called the method by accident before you do the select. Also note, that since the Active Record class has this characteristic of singularity in generating query, it is possible that you've called the method somewhere else withing another method that utilizes the Active Record class.

For example, the following will cause the `IN()` clause to be generated within the final query.

```
function a()
{
    ...
    $this->db->where_in();
    ...
    $this->b();
}

function b()
{
    // Produces the same error as stated in the question because the call of 
    // where_in() beforehand.
    $this->db->select(...)->where(...)->get(...);
}
```

P.S: Why are you doing trimming and converting the string into lowercase twice? It seems redundant to me.

Comment: I understand what you're on about and agree it is the problem, but is there a way I can reinitialise it or clear it's cache? e.g. perhaps something like $this->db->flush_cache() ??

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You could actually reset all the properties of the class back to its original state because their access modifier is public. However, I wouldn't do that if I were you. Because it doesn't seem to be a good practice. The only reason that it is written to be public (using `var` keyword)is for backward compatibility for PHP 4 (I think). So if you do something like that, the code might break in the future (If the team decided to use private/protected). There's also some methods of the class that can be used to reset these properties. However, their access modifier is protected.